# Static field that isn't shared

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following class:

```
public abstract class Manager<T> {

    protected static List<T> items = new List<T>();

    public static void Register(T item){
        if(!items.Contains(item)){
            items.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public static void DeRegister(T item){
        if(items.Contains(item)){
            items.Remove(item);
        }
    }

}
```

I then have classes that extend the above class:

```
public class InventoryManager : Manager<InventoryItem> {

}
```

Or:

```
public class ExampleManager : Manager<ExampleItem> {

}
```

The thing that will be an issue, is that `items` is static, so the two classes that extend manager will be sharing the same field. What can I do to make it so that they don't share the field yet I can still call `InventoryManager.Regiser(this)`?

Comment: `Manager<InventoryItem>` and `Manager<ExampleItem>` are *already* distinct types with distinct static fields. Your code should do exactly what you want it to.

Comment: @poke Er... What? That's not right. Static members are inherited. It's generally recommended to access them through their declaring type, but you can access them through a derived type just as well.

Comment: So `InventoryManager.items` will contain different values than `ExampleManager.items`? I thought that since manager is the class then they would both be `Manager.items` since that is where it is declared

Comment: It can't be `Manager.items`, since you don't have any `Manager` class. You only have a `Manager<T>` generic class, and each generic type argument gives you a different concrete class. A different concrete class means different static fields. You should be able to see this easily by just trying it. Add an item to `InventoryManager.items`, then inspect `ExampleManager.items.Count`.

Comment: @hvd Alright thanks! I did not know that! I thought that they still shared the fields. Thanks for the great info!

Comment: Ad runtime `InventoryManager` and `ExampleManager` will be compiled as two different types. The JIT will create two different `List<InventoryItem> ` and `List <ExampleItem>`

Comment: Note that one day you may want to inherit multiple classes from say Manager<InventoryItem>, and _they_ will share same static field reference (which might be unexpected).

Comment: @hvd Great comment. I didn't know this. I think you should make it an answer. Very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested in the comments, rephrased as an answer:

`Manager<InventoryItem>` and `Manager<ExampleItem>` are already distinct types with distinct static fields. Your code should do exactly what you want it to. You don't have any `Manager` class, you only have a `Manager<T>` generic class where each generic type argument gives you a different concrete class. A different concrete class means different static fields. You should be able to see this easily by just trying it. Add an item to `InventoryManager.items`, then inspect `ExampleManager.items.Count`.

It was also pointed out in the comments that `Manager<InventoryItem>.items` and `Manager<ExampleItem>.items` cannot be the same object, since they have different types. That's correct. However, it's worth keeping in mind that you get different static fields even for non-dependent field types.

```
using System;

class GenericBaseClass<T>
{
    public static int field;
}

class DerivedClass1 : GenericBaseClass<DerivedClass1>
{
}

class DerivedClass2 : GenericBaseClass<DerivedClass2>
{
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DerivedClass1.field = 2;
        DerivedClass2.field = 3;
        Console.WriteLine($"DerivedClass1.field: {DerivedClass1.field}");
        Console.WriteLine($"DerivedClass2.field: {DerivedClass2.field}");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
DerivedClass1.field: 2
DerivedClass2.field: 3
```

Answer (score -1):

Static fields or properties not related to instance object. They are related to type object.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx

You should declare Register and DeRegister methods as non static.

In addition

```
protected static List<T> items = new List<T>();
```

will not be the same field for both types as depending on T it will be different types.